# run docker-based rshiny app under a subfolder

Tags: r, docker, shiny

I want to develop a Shiny App in docker container, and run this app under a subfolder. Till now I just made it run and opened it through localhost:3838, how can I open it through localhost:3838/myapp?
My dockerfile is as follows:

```
FROM rocker/shiny
# Install system requirements for index.R as needed
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    --no-install-recommends \
    git-core \
    libssl-dev \
    libcurl4-gnutls-dev \
    curl \
    libsodium-dev \
    libxml2-dev \
    libicu-dev \
    && apt-get clean \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
ENV _R_SHLIB_STRIP_=true
COPY Rprofile.site /etc/R
RUN R -e "install.packages('shiny', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
RUN R -e "install.packages('remotes', repos='http://cran.rstudio.com/')"
COPY . /srv/shiny-server/
USER shiny
EXPOSE 3838
CMD ["/usr/bin/shiny-server"]
```

add I built and ran the container by the command:

```
docker build -t myapp .
docker run --rm -p 3838:3838 myapp
```